# Need to get gps positions , If app is killing or destroy in android

Tags: android, gps, destroy

One of my android app needs to get gps positions, if the app is in destroy state. My app get gps positions currently  when it is in `running(active)` and `pause(background)` modes. But when I destroyed my app, the service is running but the `LocationListener` `onLocationChanged(Location location)` not calling. How can I deal this type of issues?.

```
public class LocationFinder extends Service {
public static double lat, lng;
LocationManager locationManager;

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);



    Log.v("location", "===>location ed  onStartCommand " + lat + "==>"
            + lng);

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getLocation();

        }
    });

    return START_STICKY;
}

final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

 // this method is not called when we destroyed the app. i want to call this method even app is in destoyed.
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        updateWithNewLocation(location);


        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Location Finder : onLocation Changed "
                        + location.getLatitude() + " "
                        + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        updateWithNewLocation(null);

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};

public Location getLocation() {
    Variables.writeLog("Enter into getLocation : \n", false);
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);
    Location location = null;
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    Log.v("Location", "Before");
    if (locationManager != null) {
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (provider != null) {

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 0,
                        locationListener);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 0,
                            locationListener);
                    if (location != null) {
                        updateWithNewLocation(location);
                    } else {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                        updateWithNewLocation(location);
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                                10, 0, locationListener);
                    }
                } else {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    updateWithNewLocation(location);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10, 0,
                            locationListener);
                }
            } else {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                updateWithNewLocation(location);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10, 0,
                        locationListener);
            }
        } else {
            if (locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 0,
                        locationListener);
            } else if (locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10, 0,
                        locationListener);

            } else if (locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 10, 0,
                        locationListener);
            }
        }
    }
    return location;
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

    if (location != null) {
        Log.v("location", "===>location ed  " + lat);

        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();

        Variables.writeLog("Lat :" + lat + " lng : " + lng, false);

    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: @Kristy have you solved your problem?

Comment: @Jas, Please see my post once, i am edited my post with code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to create background Service which will work in the background and do that job for you check those links
[link 1](http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android)
[link 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

You can start this services when your activity is destroyed and the stop it when your app is resumed

Comment: My problem is not solved, I am getting positions through service. i Have a small doubt ,onLocationChanged(Location location) method calling or not when app destroyed.

Comment: So you just need to get latitude and longitude of the user location?

Answer (score 0):

You Have to run background service which will recieve locations using gps.

```
public class AndroidLocationServices extends Service {

WakeLock wakeLock;

private LocationManager locationManager;

public AndroidLocationServices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(this.POWER_SERVICE);

    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotSleep");

    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created",
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.e("Google", "Service Created");

}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    new ToggleGPS(getApplicationContext()).turnGPSOn();

    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started",
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("Google", "Service Started");

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            5000, 5, listener);

}

private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("Google", "Location Changed");

        if (location == null)
            return;

        if (isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext())) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

                jsonObject.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                jsonObject.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());

                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

                Log.e("request", jsonArray.toString());

                new LocationWebService().execute(new String[] {
                        Constants.TRACK_URL, jsonArray.toString() });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    new ToggleGPS(getApplicationContext()).turnGPSOff();
    wakeLock.release();

}

public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

I found this code in github. it works , I have used it in my appilcation.
[GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/atishtechage/backgroundgps)

Comment: You have not mentioned that you have a service which uses location manager to get gps coordinates in background, thats why I answered the above. Anyhow it would be better if you post your code

Comment: If you read his question u will see that he already achieved location services staff but he want to know how to make it running in background plz  try to put him on the road and don't give complete code

Comment: Exactly @Tony if you read my answer it explains how to use LocationManager  in service so that you can get coordinates when app is not running. Fyi your answer shows how to create locationmanager and how to create service, but dont says how to run LocationManager in service.